# Can't create a subscription to a group calendar's event in app-only

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar, microsoft-graph-webhooks

In one of my solutions I intended to create a Microsoft Graph subscription to a group calendar events resource from an Azure Function authenticated with app client credentials

Permissions granted to the app principal are `Calendars.ReadWrite` and `Group.ReadWrite.All`
[image]

So the payload of the call looks like

```
{
  "changeType": "updated",
  "resource": "groups/a619f4ce-7538-47c3-8feb-f5df845c5e96/calendar/events",
  "expirationDateTime": "2020-03-20T00:00:00Z",
  "notificationUrl": "https://4ed2bafd.ngrok.io/api/Webhook"
}
```

And the error 400 I get is

```
Exception: Error: Error making HttpClient request in queryable [400] Bad Request ::> {
[18/03/2020 19:19:39]   "error": {
[18/03/2020 19:19:39]     "code": "InvalidRequest",
[18/03/2020 19:19:39]     "message": "Subscription to a group's 'conversations' is not supported with Application-level permissions.",
[18/03/2020 19:19:40]     "innerError": {
[18/03/2020 19:19:40]       "request-id": "6337f57d-a266-4947-9f3b-289c8d8c9c9e",
[18/03/2020 19:19:40]       "date": "2020-03-18T19:19:40"
[18/03/2020 19:19:40]     }
[18/03/2020 19:19:40]   }
[18/03/2020 19:19:40] }
```

The same call works well when creating the subscription with the Graph Explorer (so with my signed-in user being part of that group).

I understand, I can't use app-only permissions to get conversations from groups and there are limitations on shared outlook objects, but I could have expected to be able to subscribe to a particular group calendar events (Which, BTW, are not "conversations" as stated in the error message). 
Is it possible, or should it be done maybe differently ?

Cheers,

Yannick

Answer (score 0):

This is a [documented known issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#permissions-for-groups-and-microsoft-teams) today. There is a [uservoice idea](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/18747862-app-authentication-to-retrieve-conversation-messag) requested the ability to read group conversations with app only context (which is highly related to your request), maybe you could add a comment to request subscription support as well and upvote the idea to help prioritize the request.